# How can I create a container with equal padding between wrapping elements and the border

Tags: css, flexbox, less

I am creating a container (which needs to behave responsively for multiple device widths) which can contain a number of different tags. The container needs to have either a consistent padding around the edges and between the rows of wrapped elements, or the elements should have the appropriate margins in place to behave in the same way.

I'm having difficulty getting it to behave how I want and currently it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the top row is perfect; however, the second row has two issues:

1. The space between the element in the second row and the elements in the first row is twice what it needs to be.
2. The second row does not have any space on the left of the element.

Currently this is my code:

```
// Components
const InputContainer = styled.ul`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 0.06rem ${colours.darkBluePrimary};
    border-radius: 0.6rem;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
    appearance: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.6rem;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
`;

const Tag = styled.li`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: ${colours.darkBluePrimary};
    border-radius: 0.6rem;

    &:first-child {
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }
`;
```

Obviously my approach for using the `&:first-child` selector will not work. But I am struggling to figure out a way for this to work.

Comment: don't put margin on the bottom? If you use CSS grid, there's a nice `gap` property.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is having the left margin be `0` and all the other margins be `1rem`. This means that the first column doesn't have a left margin either, but you added one manually in

> &:first-child {
> margin-left: 1rem;
> }

You can do this for the second row as well, but that would not solve the `2rem` spacing between the rows. So what I think you should do is make all margins `0.5rem`, then add `padding-left` and `padding-top` to the parent element (the container), and set those values at `0.5rem`. Hope this helps!